# Vaadin example project having trouble with @ManyToMany

Tags: jpa, many-to-many, vaadin, h2

This is a follow up question to [Vaadin example project having trouble with @OneToMany @ManyToOne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77943523/vaadin-example-project-having-trouble-with-onetomany-manytoone)
(For the sake of asking questions one at a time)

Here is my public example project which is simplified and reproduces the scenario I'm struggling with: https://github.com/sketchbook22/help

The machine I'm developing on is using java version

java --version
java 19.0.1 2022-10-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 19.0.1+10-21)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.1+10-21, mixed mode, sharing)
I created this project from VaadinStart then modified it. I was able to get a @OneToOne mapping to work. And with the help I received in my last question @OneToMany and @ManyToOne are working as well(Yay!) I have not been able to get a bidirectional JPA @ManyToMany mapping to work.  I have been struggling with this just as long, but isolated it out of the previous question.

I would like SamplePerson to have 2 cars which can also have other SamplePerson(s) as drivers.
the related data.sql

```
insert into car(version, id, color) values (1, 1, 'cocoa')
insert into car(version, id, color) values (1, 2, 'cream')
insert into sample_person(version, id, ape, cars, d, e) values (1, 1, 1, ARRAY [1, 2], 'd', 'e')
```

the relevant part of Car.java

```
@JsonBackReference
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="cars")
private Set<SamplePerson> drivers;
```

the relevant part of SamplePerson.java

```
@JsonManagedReference
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "CAR_DRIVER_ASSOC",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="CAR_ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="ID")}
)
private Set<Car> cars;
```

The relevant parts of the errors from the output of `mvnw`

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-02-06T13:03:22.325-05:00 ERROR 9620 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in com.example.application.Application: Failed to execute SQL script statement #4 of file [C:\git\help\target\classes\data.sql]: insert into sample_person(version, id, ape, cars, d, e) values (1, 1, 1, ARRAY [1, 2], 'd', 'e')
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1773) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
...
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #4 of file [C:\git\help\target\classes\data.sql]: insert into sample_person(version, id, ape, cars, d, e) values (1, 1, 1, ARRAY [1, 2], 'd', 'e')
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:282) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
...
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "CARS" not found; SQL statement:
insert into sample_person(version, id, ape, cars, d, e) values (1, 1, 1, ARRAY [1, 2], 'd', 'e') [42122-224]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:514) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
```

Comment: Looks like `SAMPLE_PERSON.CARS` can no longer be used, because you
changed the relation to be mapped with a dedicated table?  IMHO pick
a side: if you think the DB and your data is not important, then get rid
of your last SQL files and just use code and don't look into the DB,
because you will see horrors unimaginable.  Or don't let hibernate
generate tables, add some migration library, write your DDLs, and only
learn how to tell hibernate what you have.

Comment: @cfrick thank you for the feedback, I did not realize I was mixing sides...  However I do not understand how to move forward with your feedback.  I'm going to need a database, and I'm going to need (at)ManyToMany relationships.  The h2 in memory database is what Vaadin recommends as a placeholder while I figure out my application, I don't see how removing the data.sql would help at this point.  I could remove the (at)JoinTable annotation if you think that would help, but I read somewhere that every (at)ManyToMany relationship requires that.

Comment: @cfrick, I think I understand now that I need to create an association table which will have a ManyToOne reference to the SamplePerson and a ManyToOne reference to the Car.  I will attempt this in the example project and submit a git version if that works out.

Comment: Didn't I answer your question already?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli You answered my last question about OneToMany and ManyToOne.  This question is about ManyToMany.

Answer (score 0):

@CFrick Thanks again for your nudge in the right direction in the comment.

I now understand that ManyToMany relationships can be accomplished via an Association Table which I was able to figure out while still using the Vaadin example code's AbstractEntity and the h2 in memory database.

I made a tag/release in the public GitHub project incase it can help others.
https://github.com/sketchbook22/help/releases/tag/after_77949994

I have more questions but those will be separate SO posts. Thanks so much!